# Replacing and then stringing multiple DLLs

Tags: vb.net, dll, proxy

I'm using VB.net so keep that in mind.

I'm trying to create a program that is highly edible.  Users will be able to change multiple things by just replacing the existing dlls.  Kind of like a modding ability.

The new DLL shouldn't have to recreate every function though, it should only include the ones that it changes and then hook to the old dll for anything that it doesn't have.  Is there a way to dynamically do this?  Reference another dll (like a proxy) through yourself for anything that doesn't exist in its self?

Sorry if that is confusing.  If it still confuses people, I'll draw a picture later =)

I'm Sorry, but it must be done this way.  I have already set up everything in the manor and told clients (they have already started developing).

Comment: I think you're looking for a plug-in architecture. Interfaces are a good way to implement this. [Check here](http://geekswithblogs.net/WTFNext/archive/2009/05/06/how-to-create-a-plugin-architecture-in-vb.net.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Well, I made an edit to my post.  You see, I have to utilize the stated method for this particular project.

Comment: Your question gives merely vague sketches about how you *think* this might work. And then you say that you've already *implemented* this design pattern and handed it off to clients who have already started development. Surely they can't be doing development without a carefully documented specification of how they're supposed to interop with your application. So can you let us in on that, too? I thought you were asking because you didn't know if/how this was possible. It sounds like you've moved quite a bit beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to write a plugin architecture into your application, why re-invent the wheel, take a look at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx)

Comment: Well, I made an edit to my post.  You see, I have to utilize the stated method for this particular project.

Comment: You don't have much there in the way of "stated method". What you're describing can certainly be done (dynamically loading dlls, see Assembly.Load), but there's really not enough to go on to give much more info than that.

Comment: I've gone back and updated clients on this huge change.  I'm using Cody Grays method, however, he didn't post it as an answer.  Richard Friends reply is the next best thing.  I'll be marking it as the answer.